# Ionic app video does not play in mobile

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I am trying to have a video as a background mask in my **ionic** app.

```
<video autoplay loop poster="oceans.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="/asset/www/img/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

This is the code I am using to do so. It works on web browser but sadly not on mobile.

I did some research on it and added **crosswalk** plugin to my project but even after that I am getting following **error when I am building my .apk** file

```
C:\Users\sif-\Desktop\vConnect_project\vConnect>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\sif-\Desktop\vConne
ct_project\vConnect\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\sif-\
Desktop\vConnect_project\vConnect
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
null
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/or
g/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core
_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > repo1.maven.org
      > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://download.01.org/crosswalk
/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metad
ata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswal
k/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml'.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.916 secs
               > download.01.org

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\sif-\Desktop\vCo
nnect_project\vConnect\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\sif-\
Desktop\vConnect_project\vConnect\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.da
emon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

This is my ionic version info

```
C:\Users\sif-\Desktop\vConnect_project\vConnect>ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.15
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.2
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v4.4.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please make sure you can visit the link below by your browser and also configure the proxy if you're using.

https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml

If your network connection is okay and the problem still exists. Please try to modify the `config.xml` in the root directory of your project. You can see the configuration about the version of Crosswalk.

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_beta:18+" />
```

change it to:

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library:18+" />
```